# Unable to import tables and data from .dmp file from S3 to AWS RDS

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, datapump

I am trying to import data from .dmp file from AWS S3 to my RDS instance Oracle DB.
I am able to download the file from S3 to my oracle directory DATA_PUMP_DIR.
I am able to run the below script and able to view the dump file here.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR(p_directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'));
```

But when I try to import the data from this dump file I am getting error saying invalid arguments. What needs to be done?

The command I have used:

```
DECLARE
  hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
  hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( 
    operation => 'IMPORT', 
    job_mode  => 'FULL', 
    job_name  => null);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( 
    handle    => hdnl, 
    filename  => 'testDump.dmp', 
    directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', 
    filetype  => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file,
    reusefile => 1
   );
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( 
    handle    => hdnl, 
    filename  => 'testDump.log', 
    directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', 
    filetype  => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_log_file);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''Test_SCHEMA'')');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Importing using Oracle Data Pump](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.DataPump.html)

> When you use Oracle Data Pump to import data into an Oracle DB
> instance, we recommend the following best practices:
>
> Perform imports in **schema** or **table** mode to import specific schemas and
> objects.
>
> Limit the schemas you import to those required by your application.
>
> **Don't import in full mode.**
>
> Because Amazon RDS for Oracle does not allow access to SYS or SYSDBA
> administrative users, importing in full mode, or importing schemas for
> Oracle-maintained components, might damage the Oracle data dictionary
> and affect the stability of your database.

```
DECLARE
  hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
  hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( 
    operation => 'IMPORT', 
    job_mode  => 'SCHEMA', 
    job_name  => null);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( 
    handle    => hdnl, 
    filename  => 'testDump.dmp', 
    directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', 
    filetype  => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( 
    handle    => hdnl, 
    filename  => 'testDump.log', 
    directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', 
    filetype  => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_log_file);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''Test_SCHEMA'')');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;
```

Comment: I tried to import in the schema mode but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: need remove reusefile => 1

Comment: try  Test_SCHEMA  type in upper case.